# Maven: Create directory when needed in target

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I have JUnit-tests within my Maven project that save an image to a folder within the target directory. I want Maven to create this folder during the build phase if it doesn't already exist. I thought it might be possible to achieve this by adding a directory within the pom.xml but can't find any documentation about it.
Do I need to use a plugin for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create new file with `new File("target", "<directory>/<file>")`. then `file.mkDirs()`, It will create directory in `target` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do this within a ImageIO.write method but when I run the test I get an java.IO.FileNotFoundException (no such file or directory). Am I missing something?

Comment: i updated my answer check it now. You need create directories for that path.